# Hapijs using both Http and Https on one connection

Tags: security, https, hapi.js

New to [Hapijs](http://hapijs.com/) and trying to use it to create an app that uses HTTPS for all requests and redirect HTTP to the secure connection.The problem is the app goes in HTTPS mode no problem but if i change the URL to HTTP the server does not respond and don't know the reason why.

This is what i have came up with so far, it works but not for HTTP

```
var connectionOptions = {
    port: 3000,
    tls: {
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'key/key.pem'), 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'key/cert.pem'), 'utf8')
    }
};

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection(connectionOptions);

//This method not called when its HTTP
server.ext('onRequest', function (request, reply) {
     if (request.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'http') {
            reply.redirect('https://' + request.headers.host +
                            request.url.path).code(301);
            return reply.continue();
      }
      reply.continue();       
});

var routes = require('./routes')(server);
server.route(routes);

if (!module.parent) {
    server.start(function () {
         console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
    });
 }
```

How to force all request to be HTTPS.
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't use http and https on the same connection. Behind the scenes Hapi will create a Node `http` server *or* an `https` server depending on your `tls` config, as shown in this line from `lib/connection.js`:

`this.listener = this.settings.listener || (this.settings.tls ? Https.createServer(this.settings.tls) : Http.createServer());`

You should create another connection to your server that doesn't use TLS and then redirect non-TLS requests to the https url.

**EXAMPLE**

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Fs = require('fs');
const Url = require('url');

const config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    http: { port: 3001 },
    https: {
        port: 3000,
        key: Fs.readFileSync('key.key'),
        cert: Fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
    }
}

const server = new Hapi.Server();

// https connection

server.connection({
    port: config.https.port,
    tls: {
        key: config.https.key,
        cert: config.https.cert
    }
});

// http connection

server.connection({ port: config.http.port });

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        reply('Hello world');
    }
});

server.ext('onRequest', (request, reply) => {

    if (request.connection.info.port !== config.https.port) {

        return reply.redirect(Url.format({
            protocol: 'https',
            hostname: request.info.hostname,
            pathname: request.url.path,
            port: config.https.port
        }));
    }

    return reply.continue();
});

server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    console.log('Started server');
});
```

**EDIT**

If you're allowing insecure connections to your server before redirecting to HTTPS, consider also employing [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/HTTP_strict_transport_security) to prevent MITM attacks. You can set HSTS headers using the route config `security` option:

```
server.route({
    config: {
        security: {
            hsts: {
                maxAge: 15768000,
                includeSubDomains: true,
                preload: true
            }
        }
    },
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Figured that much, thank you but is there some example showing good practice in setting it up or is it bad idea and am better of using a single connection HTTP, cause am thinking of deploying it to Heroku and don't know the policy of having two servers running together in a single app.Again thank you for the help

Comment: @ramon22 I've added an example to the answer. I'm not too sure about Heroku as I've never used it but you're probably right, I imagine they would take care of the SSL termination themselves and always proxy HTTP traffic to you. In which case you would indeed want to check the `x-forwarded-proto` header and redirect based on the value of that instead.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution that justs reroutes every http call, no checks on every request.
You must use 2 connections though.

```js
// create the 2 connections and give the http one a specific label e.g. http
// apply the http catch all route to only the http connection
// I make use of connection label to make sure I only register the catch all route on the http connection
server.select('http').route({
    method: '*',
    path: '/{p*}',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        // redirect all http traffic to https
        // credit to Matt for the URL.format
        return reply.redirect(Url.format({
            protocol: 'https',
            hostname: request.info.hostname,
            pathname: request.url.path,
            port: config.https.port
        })).permanent();
    },
    config: {
        description: 'Http catch route. Will redirect every http call to https'
    }
});
```

For more info on the redirect see [the docs](http://hapijs.com/api#response-object-redirect-methods)

Comment: Any benchmarks to indicate the above answer isn't performant? It's only comparing two numbers that are already in memory, which I imagine is very, very cheap.

Comment: My wording is probably a bit off. Sorry for that. The main difference between our solutions is that your solution does the check on every request while mine will just reroute every http call, no check and only on http requests. Your actual redirect does seem better. Let me update my answer.