# Nodejs + Hapi + SSL/TLS + OATH2 + JWTs as Bearer

Tags: node.js, api, ssl, jwt, hapi.js

what I am trying to accomplish is to create as much as possible a secured **API** written on **NodeJS**, it must be used from mobile devices.

We had bought an **SSL** **certificate** from **Comodo** for a single domain with multiple sub domains, the certificate is installed and configured by my VPS provider.

I've trying to find some tuts for integrating **nodejs** + **hapi** + **oath2 with JWTs** + **SSL/TLS**.

Comment: Why are using both SSL/TLS with OAuth2 + JWT. Seems like 3 factor authentication. This is degrade the server performance. Try to use one as much as possible.

Comment: SSL/TLS is not about authentication but transport layer security. SSL/TLS should be used always regardless of authentication method.

Answer (score 0):

For JWT authentication in Hapi, you can use [hapi-auth-jwt2](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2). There are some other JWT plugins also, but this seems to be the most mature one. See their Github page for documentation and examples on how to configure it.

For setting up SSL/TLS/HTTPS, you could check examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650829/hapijs-using-both-http-and-https-on-one-connection). Basically, you set up two Hapi connections: one with port for HTTP traffic, one with port for HTTPS (i.e. SSL/TLS) traffic.

Additionally, I recommend reading [dwyl's introduction on JWT](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-json-web-tokens) (there are many such introductions, but this is short and easy to understand, imho).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the question was asked 6 months ago.

1. The approach we used was nginx handling trafic over SSL/TLS and proxy requests to nodejs server via localhost http.

2. First Authorization server (oauth2 server using the oauthjs/node-oauth2-server written for express)

3. Second resource server (our main web service written on hapi)

4. Using a a simple library for parsing JWT tokens on hapi server.